# TestApplication with Qt5.9 and embedded linux on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

Setting up Qt5.9 on my RaspberryPi3 with raspbian-lite version of image.
Next compile test application qtbase/examples/opengl/qopenglwidget
With run I can see next message

```
QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/fonts.
Note that Qt no longer ships fonts. Deploy some (from http://dejavu-fonts.org for example) or switch to fontconfig.
```

Application was running, but there is no any text.

I want to use standard fonts, but I don't now how I can do it. 
OR, How to use FREE-Types from http://dejavu-fonts.org.
Please help me, somebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found right answer. It was very simple:
You must add any font (*.ttf) in-to directory /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/fonts on raspberryPi. For example, I use free fonts from 
http://dejavu-fonts.org.